# How to get downloadURL from an object containing an array of Firebase paths

Tags: angular, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-storage

I have a product saved in Firebase Firestore. This object has keys like name and price, and an array that stores the images ref's fullPath (which are stored in Firebase Storage).

This is my service:

```
  getAllProductsOfType(type: any): any {
    return this.db.collection(type).valueChanges();
  }
```

The component:

```
export class Component {
  products = this.productService.getAllProductsOfType(this.category);
  ...
```

And the template:

```
  <mat-card *ngFor="let product of products | async">
      {{ product.name }}
  </mat-card>
```

This all works fine.

#### My problem:

I want to display the images. So I created a service:

```
  getImageUrl(path: string): any {
    return this.fireStorage.ref(path).getDownloadURL();
  }
```

But it cannot make it work, I just crash my browser (INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES) when i do this:

```
  <mat-card *ngFor="let product of products | async">
    <div class="image-holder">
      <img [src]="imageService.getImageUrl(product.imageUrls[0]) | async" />
    </div>
  </mat-card>
```

**Question:** How can I display the image(s) asynchronous?